# Switch off web part's events

Tags: web-part, event-handlers, events

I'm brand new to Sharepoint. 
How can I switch off web part's events like click and mouseover over title?

Comment: You can't. Not without setting `display:none` css property on it's surrounding CSS.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the mouseover and click events using JavaScript (easier with jQuery), which really only just use CSS to change the appearance and show controls (such as a checkbox or the verb menu).

You'd have to load your javascript/jquery via the masterpage somehow, easiest way is to open it in SharePoint Designer and place your jquery code directly in there.

If your environment is customised at all (custom web parts, branding, etc), seek advice from your solution architect first, on the best way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to remove the ability to right click throughout the entire page you can add a script to the MasterPage directly or better yet to a User Control loaded into the MasterPage that can supress the click events.

If it was only for specific web parts, then it would need to be built into that particular web part and you would capture the event on that container.